# ASP.NET (C #) Query MYSQL No response, Wait for localhost forever

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I use ASP.NET Query MYSQL database

But he did not show. Only "waiting for localhost'I waited, but did not change

But the same code in the form it is feasible

---ASP.NET

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connStr = "server=localhost;port=3306;uid=root;pwd=123123;database=testdb;";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        String cmdText = "SELECT NAME FROM playdata WHERE SID = '001'";
        command = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
        SL1.Text = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
    {
        switch (ex.Number)
        {
            case 0:
                SL1.Text = "Can not connect";
                break;
            case 1045:
                SL1.Text = "Input error";
                break;
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
    conn.Close();
}
```

---

I do not know how to solve the problem, and in ASP.NET, insert data was successful
So I do not know where wrong

---insert data

```
    string connStr = "server=localhost;port=3306;uid=root;pwd=123123;database=testdb;";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `testdb`.`playdata` (`SID`, `NAME`,`PWD`,`EMAIL`) VALUES('S01', 'MYNAME','RRR01','E4913')"; //重點
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
    {
        switch (ex.Number)
        {
            case 0:
                SL1.Text ="Connection fail";
                break;
            case 1045:
                SL1.Text ="pwd error.";
                break;
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
    conn.Close();
```

---

*edit
I use visual studio community 2015
I have tried
127.0.0.1
localhost
String cmdText = "SELECT NAME FROM playdata WHERE SID = '001'";
String cmdText = "SELECT NAME FROM`testdb`.`playdata` WHERE SID = '001' ";
String cmdText = "SELECT NAME FROM playdata WHERE SID = '001'";

Comment: replace your playdata with this `testdb`.`playdata` ,

Comment: I tried, but it does not change, this change form valid, but ASP.NET still 'for local'

Comment: What is the data type used for SID?

Comment: He is the 'VARCHAR (45)'

Comment: Does anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I try and try more teaching, I found this code is valid!

```
    string connStr = "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;uid=root;pwd=123123;database=testdb;";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();

    String cmdText = "SELECT NAME FROM playdata WHERE SID = 'S01'";
    command = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
    conn.Open();
    try {
        string str = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        SL1.Text = str;
    } catch {
        SL1.Text = "error";
    }
```

---

Cause of the problem comes from "Console.ReadLine ();"

Thanks everyone helping me!

Answer (score 3):

Update the query to:

```
String cmdText = "SELECT NAME FROM playdata WHERE SID = 'S01'";
```

You inserted SID 'S01' and were previously querying SID '001'

Comment: I tried, but again into the wait,Is the value entered in the workbench '001', 'S01' is used to test insertion,And the same is valid in the form

Answer (score 1):

Update your query to this :

```
 "SELECT NAME FROM `testdb`.`playdata` WHERE SID = '001'";
```

I have an issue with that apostrophes thing on php. It might be the same issue.

Comment: I tried, but nothing changed, and This is also valid in form